Accordion effect to show and hide texts - 2sxc
Is it possible to add accordion texts in the text editor below?
Accordion effect to show and hide texts
My idea is to insert several titles and in these titles I insert the contents relating to the titles.
enter image description here
for example:
enter image description here
I tried to insert an accordion effect, but there is no such option. FAQ type

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please take the [tour] and read [ask]

As 2sxc is an all-purpose module you should be able to create an app using standard DNN UX elements. The documentation for your needs can be found here: Panels Demo.

I believe what you want to do is to "convert" all headings in your HTML into collapsible sections.
This can be done, but it's not the responsibility of 2sxc to do it.
Basically what you'll want to do is

either write some Razor code which modifies the HTML before showing it - creating bootstrap accordions or whatever your flavor
or create some JS which finds the headings and converts into accordions.

Good luck!

The easiest thing to do is use the HTML Disclosure elements for this. You'll have to code them in HTML (source), but they are very useful and easy to style them to look like your example.
Here is what the HTML looks like, its very easy to use and you can put most any type of HTML after the Summary:
<details open>
  <summary>This is your 1st Title or Heading</summary>
  These are the extra details that will be visible when opened. 
</details>
<details>
  <summary>This is your 2nd Title or Heading</summary>
  These are the extra details that will be visible when opened. 
</details>
<details>
  <summary>This is your 3rd Title or Heading</summary>
  Round three of extra details that will be visible when opened. 
</details>

HTML Disclosure element
However, I think a better solution would be to instead use the
2sxc Accordion App
This keeps you content as structured data. And if you want to customize the look and feel, then you just copy the existing View (and code, Accordion.cshtml) and customize the output as much as you like.
Here is a simple example where we used the Accordion App v4 (2sxc app module) for the Membership Levels (below the Join Now button).
Benefits of Membership
Here is another example, a bit fancier:
Boston Bioprocess

fyi link-only answers are not valid answers. Aside from that, the question is off-topic - no programming question, just a generic opinion/idea request.
